# Vlookup returns #N/A if string contains a '

Tags: string, excel, vlookup

I am using a vlookup statement: `=VLOOKUP(B1232,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)`. The cell in B1232 contains the string:

> 'You Rawk!!~'

With the "'" inside the string that I want to go and find, the program retursn #N/A.  I believe that the Vlookup command is omitting the opening single-quote when it runs the search, is that true? Is there any way to work around this so that I can run the VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the quote is the problem - Excel uses "~" [tilde] as an "escape character" so it has a problem with values that contain "~". You can use a `SUBSTITUTE` function within your VLOOKUP to replace "~" with "~~" - when using two tildes the first one tells excel to treat the second as a literal "~", i.e. use

`=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(B1232,"~","~~"),Sheet1!A:B,2,0)`

That will work whether B1232 contains "~" or not

Comment: Worked for me. Notice it failed initially because I had to [recalculate the value of the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40976113/523742).