# Force "F2"+"Enter" on range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2010 worksheet which has macros to copy data from other sheets into a specific format on another sheet.

The data copies but I have an issue with the formatting of cell ranges which hold date or time values.

The data originates from a database extract and everything is in text format.  In my worksheet when I copy the date (via VBA) I apply the format `"yyyy-mm-dd"` for dates and `"hh:mm.ss.ss"` for times.

There is never a fixed amount of rows so I've set the VBA code to apply the formatting to the range of cells for example:

```
AssDateLastRow = shAss.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

shAss.Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Not all cells in the range have the correct format, they will appear as `15/04/2014` not `2014-04-15`.  If I manually select the cell and press the <kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys the format appears as I need.  This happens randomly through the range and there could be thousands of rows so it is not practical to trawl though the worksheet manually hitting <kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> on each one.

I've looked on the internet and found what should automatically do the <kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> with VBA.

The code below is extracted from a larger set of lines of code, so the `Dim` statements etc. are further up in the actual copy, but this should show the way I've tackled this so far.

```
Dim shAss As Worksheet
Dim AssDateLastRow As Long
Dim c As Range

'enter method to format 'Date Craftperson Assigned' and 'Time Craftperson Assigned' in   Assignments sheet
'column "C" and "D", to formats required by Archibus: date "yyyy-mm-dd", time  "hh:mm.ss.ss"
AssDateLastRow = shAss.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
shAss.Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
'ensure format is applied by forcing F2 edit of cell
For Each c In shAss.Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow).Cells
    c.Select
    SendKeys "{F2}", True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
'Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
Next
```

When I run the code, the data copies into my worksheets but the dates and times are still in a mixed format.

The attempt at forcing the <kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> via the VBA doesn't  seemed to have done anything.  If done manually it works okay.

Below is an example of data copied from the results in the worksheet

```
Work Request Code       Date Assigned       Time  Assigned
92926                   19/05/2014          14:30.00.00
92927                   19/05/2014          15:00.00.00
92928                   2014-05-19          15:15.00.00
92934                   2014-05-19          14:00.00.00
92527                   12/05/2014          07:30
92528                   12/05/2014          08:00
92804                   2014-05-12          16:15
92805                   2014-05-12          16:20.00.00
```

Comment: Ok, what do the dates/numbers look like before you execute the code? I mean what does the `date assigned` `19/05/2014` and `2014-05-19` look like before you run ANY code on it

Comment: dates 19/05/2014 and times 07:30

Comment: I mean like what is the underlying value - not what is displayed but what is in the recordset? u can try `Range("C5").Value2` but not sure this is going to work

Comment: Not sure what you mean by underlying value.  The information is copied from e.g. sheet1 to sheet2, via VBA code.  on sheets one the date are entered as dd/mm/yyyy, and the cell formating is date format of the same.  the format I'm trying to apply is after the data has been copied in to empty cells on sheet 2

Comment: Ok great, so where are you assigning and how are you qualifying your active worksheet?

Comment: With ThisWorkbook
        Set shWO = .Sheets("Workorders") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set shAss = .Sheets("Assignments") 'Modify as necessary.
    End With

Comment: Try manually replacing "-" with "-" and see if that does the job of making the dates the right format. It should work. Then you can just do that as a macro. It's fast and it works. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 19):

I use this simple macro to apply <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the currently selected range:

```
Sub ApplyF2()
    Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work same as F2+Enter. I have some blank cells that block text from the immediate left cell to flow over. F2+Enter on the problematic cell fixed the problem, but not this macro.

Comment: Doesn't convert URLs to hyperlinks. So definitely not the same as F2+Enter.

Comment: This worked for me with instead of using selection I use the range Range("H2:I" & lrow).Value = Range("H2:I" & lrow).FormulaR1C1  lrow beign the last used row

Answer (score 6):

I struggled to get this to work too.  My problem has been not just dates but also data with a single quote in front of it.  What I hacked together works great for me.  It cleans up over 70,000 cells very fast.  Hope it works for you:

(you will change the range and such to suit your needs)

```
    Dim MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Range(Cells(2, 7), [G1].End(xlDown))

    For Each MyRange In MyRange.Cells
    'Mimic F2 without SendKeys
        MyRange.Value = MyRange.Value
    Next
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two options to get Excel to apply the formatting to the cells in one step.

The first is to use the **Text to columns** functionality even though there is nothing in the column to split.
The second option is to copy a value of 1 and paste it into the cells using the **Paste Special - Multiply** option.

Although either method should force an update of the cell formating, I would lean towards the first option.
This is incase some of your dates are is stored as text.

```
    Sub Format_Text_to_Columns()

    Dim AssDateLastRow As Long

    AssDateLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
    'Set the format

        Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow).Select
        Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
         Space:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 5)
    'Use text to columns to force a format update

    End Sub



    Sub Format_Paste_Special_Multiply()

    Dim AssDateLastRow As Long

    AssDateLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
    'Set the format

        Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
        Range("C1").Copy
        Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("C1").ClearContents
    'Multiply the dates by 1 to force a format update

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim n As Integer
Dim AssDateLastRow As Long

AssDateLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set r = Range("E2:E" & AssDateLastRow)
r.Select
r.NumberFormat = "ddmmyyyy;@"
r.Select
For n = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    SendKeys "{F2}", True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
Next n
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use *Text to Columns* to solve this problem

1) Highlight the column of data

2) Go to *Data* -> *Text To Columns* -> *Delimited* -> (deselect everything) -> *Next*

3) On page 3 of the wizard, set the *Column Data Format* YMD

4) *OK*

Comment: This is the proper solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub RefreshCells()

Dim r As Range, rr As Range
Set rr = Selection
For Each r In rr
r.Select
Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Application.SendKeys "+{ENTER}"
    DoEvents
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    DoEvents

Next



End Sub
```

Comment: please explain your answer, don't just post a block of code

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you would need to send keys F2 + Enter.  What is the formatting before you run the macro?  Try formatting the whole column that way (it won't affect the text).

```
Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Comment: we have formatted the columns, that way, and when you look at the cell format it shows as the format we want (yyyy-mm-dd), but they actual data in the cell is showing as dd/mm/yyyy, but as mentioned if we manually use F2+Enter it cans the appearance in the cell to the correct format.  We just want to try automate the process

Answer (score 0):

My variation

```
n = Selection.Rows.count
Dim r1 As range, rv As range
Set r1 = Selection.Cells(1, 1)
For I = 1 To n
Set rv = r1.offset(I - 1, 0)
vali = rv.value
 IsNumeric(vali) Then
 vali = CDbl(vali)
 rv.value = 0
 rv.value = vali
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to press F9 or  File-Option-formulas-workbook calculation- automatic

Answer (score 0):

I just set the cell to the right of the top entry equal to a formula that multiplied the problem cell times 1. That new cell was a proper number, so then double clicking the handle extended it down the whole column fixed them all!

Answer (score 0):

Sendkeys are not stable. The better way is to store the text in the clipboard and paste it.

[See here on how to store values in the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard)

```
Sub CopyText(Text As String)
Dim MSForms_DataObject As Object
Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
MSForms_DataObject.SetText Text
MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard
Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Test()
CopyText (ActiveCell.Value)
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
End Sub
'In place of active cell, you may pass a range
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Sub f2Cells(sel as Range)
    Dim rng as Range

    On Error GoTo exitHere

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    For Each rng In sel.Cells
        If Not Intersect(sel, Application.Range(rng.Address)) Is Nothing And _
            Application.Range(rng.Address).EntireColumn.Hidden = False And _
            Application.Range(rng.Address).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                Application.Range(rng.Address).Application.SendKeys "({F2}{ENTER})", True
        End If
    Next rng

exitHere:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
End Sub
```

Then from your function you can just call

```
f2Cells shAss.Range("C4:C" & AssDateLastRow)
```

Comment: sel.Cells!? Does nothing. Try "Selection"

Answer (score 0):

My solution, works:

```
Sub ChangeDotWithSlash()
Dim wsActiveSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngRange As Range
Dim TextBefore As String
Dim TextAfter As String
Dim dtDate As Date
Set wsActiveSheet = ActiveSheet
For Each rngRange In wsActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:B").Cells
    rngRange.Select
    If InStr(1, rngRange.Text, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        TextBefore = rngRange.Text
        TextAfter = Replace(TextBefore, ".", "/", 1)
        If IsDate(TextAfter) Then
            dtDate = CDate(TextAfter)
            rngRange.ClearContents
            rngRange.Value = Empty
            rngRange.Value = dtDate
        End If
        dtDate = Empty
        TextBefore = Empty
        TextAfter = Empty
    End If
Next rngRange
dtDate = Empty
TextBefore = Empty
TextAfter = Empty
Set rngRange = Nothing
Set wsActiveSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

I just got it, Simple
Select all the cells you want to hit F2 and Enter and run this short macro:

Sub AutoF2Enter() 
    Selection.Value = Selection.Value
End Sub

Works on date and numbers!
50.000 cells in a second!