# Excel 2013 VBA: Copy-Pasting formulas copies the value from copied cell (in addition to the formula) instead of re-calculating

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

i am having a issue currently where when I try to copy a cell (with a formula e.g. `=A1*B1` whose value / product is `6`) and paste the formula into another cell, both the formula (now `=A2*B2`) and the copied-from cell’s value (i.e. `6`) are updated in the new cell and also, if there is a total / sum row that factors in both cells, the sum does not get updated either after the paste action.

The only time the formulas update or re-calculate is after I double click the specific cell (as if to edit) and hit ‘enter’ or if I save the page. Even when I update one of the cells which the formula calls for, the formula does not automatically recalculate. This only seems to be happening when working in any workbook with a macro(s) even though there isn’t any code in the macro that should impact this. I’m using excel in Office professional plus 2013.

I don’t recall this happening in the past so it may have started happening more recently. Any help or insight would be really appreciated. (I even tried commenting out all the macro code but the issue still persists.)

Comment: Then one of your macros is turning off automatic calculations and not turning it back on.

Comment: This may also be an issue with cell formatting. Check for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455378/excel-how-to-refresh-a-cell-to-apply-new-cell-format

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks very much for the quick response and helpful information. None of my macros had code to turn off automatic calculations (because I didn't even know that was an option) but I googled and found the code to turn it on and inserted that code into the 'Worksheet_Activate()' sub and it worked. I, then, checked the source code for another workbook that I opened recently (macros were coded by someone else), to see if that was the culprit and low and behold, it was! Seemed like it turns them off but errors out before turning them back on and it impacts my other docs. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Trymzet. There was some helpful information in there as well that will come in handy for me in future code

Comment: BTW under the formula in the options you can manually turn them on and off.

Comment: @ScottCraner, oh yes, I found it: 'Calculation Options'. Thank you!