# How to correctly solve problems with excel format numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following database sample:

[image]

The problem that I have is that if I click in the first cell in Unit_Price (185.542) what I see is 185542 so when I multiply this unit price per the amount of units sold, I get a number much bigger than it should be.

As well, I another problem, there are numbers that have a "." in the separation so excel does not identify them as a number.

**
What I tried?**

- I tried to change cells format without success because excel is taking the incorrect unit price (185542 instead of 185,54)
- I tried to replace "." for "," but it doesn't work neither.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think your question is more suited for **[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)**

Comment: Divide the Unit Price by 1000?

Comment: You have a data entry problem. The number format is **irrelevant**. The value stored is the value seen in the formula bar when you click on a cell. Changing the format only changes how it appears in the cell, and not the actual value. You need to ensure that the values are properly entered. Where are these values coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The number formatting of `Columns C an E` not identical and not corresponds to your requirements. To correct this do the followings

- Select the 2 columns and right click the selection.
- Choose **Format Cells**
- On the **Number** tab select **Number** and in **Decimal places** set 2. If you want other format e.g. thousand separators select the appropriate **Category** and choose a **Type**
  [Custom and # ##0,00]
- Click **OK**
- Enter the numbers with the proper decimal separator. This is the character which you see in the **Sample** box of the **Number** tab.

If even after this you don't get acceptable result you have to refresh the involved cells. For this follow this post [EXCEL > how to refresh a cell to apply new cell format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455378/excel-how-to-refresh-a-cell-to-apply-new-cell-format)