# Change dot formatted date to Slash format

Tags: excel

Hi all I want to change the date format from dot to slash and I have tried all ways of changing the date from control panel and also from the "Format option" in excel but nothing works.

Please would anyone can recommend how can I do this bulk change of format of date except doing it manually.
Any advices would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a screeenshot of your query or provide some markdown data so that we can copy and provide solutions accordingly

Comment: My solution worked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060831/force-f2enter-on-range-of-cells/77543989#77543989

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the value you have in the spreadsheet is a valid date.

Excel might interpret the value as plain text.

After you make sure it is a date, then you can change the date format using the cell attribute editor

You can use formatting like `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`

[image]

Comment: Yes I validated and these are not treated as valid dates so that is the reason the excel is not converting to the desired format..is there any way I can change it to a valid date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **substitute** to replace the dot with a slash, then wrap that with **datevalue** to convert to a date. Lastly, format the cell as your desired Date format (such as Short Date or Custom).

Below, column A is your original data.

Column B contains the following formula:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/"))
```

Output:

[image]